# JS: Change Date format returned from DatePicker

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

I'm not that good at JS, so I have a problem with dates.

I want to set range for my DatePickers - that's why when the date is changed, I get it in the following format:

Wed Jul 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)

I need to change it to the date in format dd/mm/yyyy to use the value later. Till now it looks like following:

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
$("#datepickerStart").on("changeDate", function (e) {
    minDate = e.date;
    console.log(minDate);  // Wed Jul 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
//        day = minDate.getDate(); <- doesn't work
//        monthIndex = minDate.getMonth();
//        year = minDate.getFullYear();
});


 $('#datepickerStart').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    startDate : new Date('01/01/2009'),
    endDate : new Date()
 });

 $('#datepickerEnd').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    startDate : minDate,//""+day+"/"+monthIndex+"/"+year,<- tried different approaches
    endDate : new Date()
 });
```

If I use minDate.format("dd/mm/yyyy"), it returns error "Uncaught TypeError: minDate.format is not a function".

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good alternative for doing this is using [momenjs](http://momentjs.com/) library.

Other alternative is that you create a `function` which formats your date as follow:

```js
var formatDate = function(d) {
  
    var date = d.getDate();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var newDate = (date < 10 ?  ('0' + date) : date) + '/' + (month < 10 ?  ('0' + month) : month) + '/' + year;

    alert(newDate);
}

// Usage example
var now = new Date();

formatDate(now)
```

Comment: Thanks for a tip. BTW, the code snippet returns 17/06/115 ;)

Comment: Answer editted, it should be `getFullYear` instead of `getYear`